# What is the scientific term for the erroneous inversion of cause and effect?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, terminology, cognition

What is the correct scientific term for the - erroneous - inversion of cause and effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [dictionary of psychology](https://books.google.com/books?id=0uxnglHzYaoC&pg=PA844) this is simply called "reverse causality"

> In attempting to understand the relationship between cause and effect, a tendency to attribute what is actually the cause to the effect. For example, does the ingestion of lead paint cause a lower intelligence quotient (IQ) or is it that children with lower IQs tend to eat lead paint?

Answer (score 0):

Would the concept of contraposition from the world of mathematical logic work for you?

From the Wikipedia explanation of [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition):

> The contrapositive of a statement has its antecedent and consequent inverted and flipped. For instance, the contrapositive of the conditional statement "If it is raining, then I wear my coat" is the statement "If I don't wear my coat, then it isn't raining."

Comment: The logical error I am looking for, is "I am wearing my coat, therefore it is raining" - to use the example.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment to the first answer...

> The logical error I am looking for, is "I am wearing my coat, therefore it is raining"

...I think you are referring to **[deductive arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning)**. A deductive argument (definition taken from [Mark Storey, Bellevue College)](https://www.bellevuecollege.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/41/2015/01/Critical-Thinking-TEXT.pdf):

> ...claims (explicitly or implicitly) that if the premises all are true, then the
> conclusion must be true

Valid examples are (taken from the linked document from Mark Storey)

> - All bats are cute animals. No cute animals are mean. So, certainly, no bats are mean.
> - Joan is Lauren’s mother. Therefore, Joan must be older than Lauren.
> - Nobody knows Ned. Therefore, it must be that Ned does not know himself.
> - Some cats are pets. Thus, some pets must be cats.

A familiar invalid example is the following (taken from memory on my own Philosophy class, a long, long time ago):

> All cows have 4 legs. It has 4 legs, thus it must be a cow.

Your question proper states that it should be related to cause and effect. In terms of deductive reasoning, however, it is based on *premises* and *conclusions*. Quoting Mark Storey again:

> [T]he argument may fail in its aim; what makes the argument deductive is that it
> is the kind of argument that—if it were successful—would have the premises absolutely
> guarantee the conclusion to be true.

I think what you are after are examples where the *premises* do not guarantee the *conclusion* to be true. This is different from causes and effects, though.